# Test-Path with variable foldername

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to check whether a folder exists based on variables:

```
$folderdate = (Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd")
$foldername = "C:\Scripts\temp\$folderdate"

$path = $foldername

if (!(Test-Path $path)) {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("No folder :/ ")
    exit
}
```

Every time I run the script, it drops the custom error message "No folder :/ " even if it's there.

If I try

```
$CheckFolder = Test-Path "C:\Scripts\temp\Folder"

if ($CheckFolder) {
    continue
} else {
    $wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    $wshell.Popup("No folder :/ ")
    exit
}
```

it works properly. I also tried without `$` and the script has the same behavior.
I tried `$path = "C:\Scripts\temp\$foldername"` but that drops a

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (C:\Scripts\temp\C:\Scripts\temp\20180624:String) [Test-Path], NotSupportedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsNotSupportedError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand error.
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Are you sure the full path to the folder is correct and you have access to it?

Comment: Yes the path was correct, I wonder how the first code worked for you

Comment: Still works.  I copied your code exactly to a PS1 file, then created an appropriate folder. I go no output while the folder was there, and a popup when I deleted it, which seems like the expected behaviour.  Could be a quirk of permissions, PSVersions, host environment, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited after comment from Ansgar

The following works

```
if (!(Test-Path $path))
```

Also in the second test you tried, $foldername already contained a path, which means you concatenated two paths names. The exception is reporting it:

```
C:\Scripts\temp\C:\Scripts\temp\20180624
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that PowerShell [auto-casts other types to boolean](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) if required, using a negation (`!`, `-not`) with a boolean value is perfectly fine. Or rather, it's not just fine, these operators were *made* for boolean expressions. Doing `$false -eq EXPRESSION` just obfuscates things.